# DepthFirstInOrer in JS - test code fail to print the value

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-tree, depth-first-search

I've created a method to traverse Depth first in order with a recursion in my BinaryTree class.

I don't understand where to add this.value for the value of my left child and right child to be received in my test code as expected. I've tried every possible place but without success. when I use console.log to debug, i can only manage to get the value or [Function (anonymous)]

**Method:**

```
      traverseDepthFirstInOrder(fn) {

    //handle left child (if exists)
    if (this.left) {
      this.left.traverseDepthFirstInOrder(fn);
    }
    //handle right child (if exists)
    if (this.right) {
      this.right.traverseDepthFirstInOrder(fn);
    }
  }
```

**testCode:**

```
test("should call the fn on left nodes, center nodes, then right nodes", () => {
let test = [];
      binaryTree.add(4);
      binaryTree.add(14);
      binaryTree.add(6);
      binaryTree.add(16);
      binaryTree.add(2);
      binaryTree.add(12);
      binaryTree.traverseDepthFirstInOrder(e => test.push(e.value));
      expect(test).toEqual([2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 14, 16]);
    });
```

terminal failed:

- Expected  - 9

  - Received  + 1

Comment: You never call `fn`?

Comment: @trincot i'm new at coding and not use to some keywords, could you be more precise on what you mean when you say "never call fn".

Answer (score 0):

This was what was meant in trincot's comment.  This is supposed to traverse the tree in an `inorder` manner, calling the supplied function on every node.  But you don't call the function.  You're missing one line:

```js
class Tree {
  constructor (value, left = null, right = null) {this.value = value; this .left = left; this .right = right}
  
  traverseDepthFirstInOrder (fn) {
    //handle left child (if exists)
    if (this.left) {
      this.left.traverseDepthFirstInOrder(fn);
    }
    // handle the root node
    fn (this)               //  *** This line was missing ***
    //handle right child (if exists)
    if (this.right) {
      this.right.traverseDepthFirstInOrder(fn);
    }
  }
}

const binaryTree = new Tree (10, new Tree (4, new Tree (2), new Tree (6)), new Tree (14, new Tree (12), new Tree (16)))

let test = [];
binaryTree.traverseDepthFirstInOrder(e => test.push(e.value));
      
console .log (test)
```

Ignore the constructor and my method of creating the tree; I don't have the rest of the class you're using.  But this change should fix your version as well.

Comment: ohhh I see! now I understand, cause DFS is: left child, then root node, then right child. And i was missing that root node step. Thank you so much Scott, it really helped me to understand better DFS!!!

Comment: `left -> root -> right` is specifically  an `inorder` traversal, a specific type of depth-first traversal.  `preorder` (`root -> left -> right`) and `postorder` (`left -> right -> root`) are two others.  The most common alternative is a breadth-first, which scans it level-by-level.